# Is there a correlation between Animal Intelligence x Playing time?

Tags: intelligence, learning

I'm writing a small text for a blog about playing time and I wish to have more resources about the correlation between Intelligence and Playing time in animals. If not exactly that, maybe some indications leading to this conclusion or even going against it. Correlations between playing time and animals sociability are welcome too.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "playing time".

Comment: Great, thanks for the interest James. By playing time I mean the time dedicated to playing activities, as in small cubs playing together or with their mother, or chimps chasing one another with the intention of "having fun". I know the concept is very hard to define in behaviourism, but I wish to get some insights regarding to this. I wish to correlate this in order to show how playing is important to learning not only in humans but also in animals. Pardon for the innacuracy of the terms I use.

Comment: @FernandoTsukumo I am afraid, that the concept of (measurable) intelligence might be as hard to define (especially for animals), as is playing time. Are you looking to compare the same species of animals, but little ones play more or less or are you looking to generally compare animals that play a lot to animals that do not play as much?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yeah, I am aware this wouldn't be an easy task, just decided to try a long shot... who knows? Actually, I am trying to find some evidence to something I feel, which is a link between the need of playing time and learning or maybe playing time and sociability among a good number of animal species or even just mammals. I saw that discussion about life expectancy x intelligence and then I got all hopeful about finding something similar regarding playing time. Maybe an impossible task: At least for now?